# How to get Key, Value from dictionary when value is a list

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, keyvaluepair

so basically I have a dictionary where I have a key, and then the value is a list that contains strings.. so for example..

```
{"key1", list1}
list1 = [Value 1 Value2, Value3]
```

And I have multiple keys and therefore values that have lists.
I want to display it so that it shows

```
Key1: Value1
Key1: Value2
Key1: Value3
```

So I want to be able to display the Key and also the value. But I am unsure of how to do that.

```
foreach (var value in FoodCategory_Item.Values)
{
    foreach(var item in value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value of the Dictionary Item is: {0}", item);
    }
}
```

That's what I have so far, which is to iterate over the values, which I know how to do, but I am not sure how to get the key values in there as well, because it will iterate over all the values first, and then iterate through the key items..

Comment: If you need keys too, don't iterate over `Values` :) Just iterate over the dictionary (each element is a key value pair), then within that, iterate over all of the values for that key.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in FoodCategory_Item)
{
    foreach (string item in kvp.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, item);
    }
}
```

[`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so you can iterate over it directly.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much! I thought that since I was iterating through the key's, the key's wouldn't stay, and it would move on to the next key. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation for Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), you will notice that it implements the interface

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Hence, you can do the following:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<TKeyType, TValueType> kvp in dictionary)
{
    foreach(var item in kvp.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, item);
    }
}
```

In the example code given here, replace *TKeyType* with the actual type of the keys used in your dictionary, and replace *TValueType* with the list type used for the the values of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is enumerable, so iterate that:

```
foreach (var kvp in FoodCategory_Item)
{
     foreach(var item in kvp.Value)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Value of the Dictionary Key {0} is: {1}", kvp.Key ,item);
     }
}
```